# Object calls function without arguments to a function that requires an argument

Tags: c++, header-files

So I am working with another firm's code in C++ and I am not to familiar with C++ common practices and the following seems strange to me.

I have an object in a .cpp file I will call file1, that calls a member function without any arguments. If I look where the class of that object and that method are defined, in a .cpp file I will denote file2, that function in question takes a single float as an argument. However, in a separate .h file that both file1 and file2 #include, there is a Function prototype of that function, however the float is assigned a particular value.

So what is exactly going on here and what was the motivation for it?

Comment: Look up "default arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the float is uninitialized when the member function is called, the default value used in the prototype will be assigned to it.  If that float has a value when the member function is called, the default is ignored.